# Rename Buit-in php Functions without Using PECL Extension

Tags: php, pecl

I want to replace 'date' function with another function. Using 'rename_function' and 'override_function' are a solution for me, but is there any other way to solve the problem without using PECL extension?

Comment: Namespacing is an alternative - but why do you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: The function has been used many times in a large code and I want to change the return value. I would appreciate if you could give more details about namespacing solution.

Comment: For namespacing, the first place to look is the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php)

Comment: [Demo](https://3v4l.org/1EefD)

Comment: If you're using the `use LocalOverrides\date;` at the top of your code, then PHP will always check for the version of the `date()` function in the namespace `LocalOverrides`..... other functions beside `date()` will not be affected in any way.... and this is probably as small as you can make the change, perhaps with an auto-prepend file to define the namespaced function, and with a `use` aliasing at the top of each script file

Comment: You don't need to wrap all the code in every script file in the `namespace {` (global namespace).... that's only in my demo because I'm defining both namespaces in the same file

Comment: @MarkBaker: I know, I have tested it, It's not working the the result is the default value by the built-in date, you can test this in the demo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a perfect solution because you must add `use function` in your php files. (`use function` works on php 5.6.0 or above):

```
namespace OverriddenFunctions {
    function target($arg1) {
        return "Overridden result!"
    }
}

namespace {
    use function OverriddenFunctions\target;
    echo target('arg1');
}
```

Thanks to Mark Baker.